# Issue with signing in to an application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an issue regarding signing in..!

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity

   {
       private Button CreateAccountButton;
       private EditText InputName, InputPhoneNumber, InputPassword;
       private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
       FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        CreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_register_btn);
        InputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username_input);
        InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password_input);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_phone_number_input);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        

        CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CreateAccount();
                

            }
        });

    }

       private void CreateAccount()
       {
           String name = InputName.getText().toString();
           String phone = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
           String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();
           if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
           {
               Toast.makeText(this, "please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
          else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
           {
               Toast.makeText(this, "please enter your phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
          else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
           {
               Toast.makeText(this, "please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
           {
               loadingBar.setTitle("Create Account");
               loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, While we are checking the credentials");
               loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
               loadingBar.show();

               validatephonenumber(name, phone, password);

           }


       }

       private void validatephonenumber(final String name, final String phone, final String password)
       {
           final DatabaseReference RootRef;
           RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

           RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
            {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
               {
                  if(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phone).exists())
                  { Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "this" +phone+ "alredy exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      loadingBar.dismiss();
                      Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please try using another phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      Intent intent= new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);

                  }
                  else
                  {

                      HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                      userdataMap.put("Phone", phone);
                      userdataMap.put("password", password);
                      userdataMap.put("name", name);

                      RootRef.child("User").child(phone).updateChildren(userdataMap)
                              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                  {
                                      if (task.isSuccessful())
                                      {
                                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Congratulations your account has been created ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                          loadingBar.dismiss();

                                          Intent intent= new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
                                          startActivity(intent);
                                      }

                                      else
                                      {
                                          loadingBar.dismiss();
                                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Network Error: Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                      }



                                  }
                              });
                  }

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });

       }
   }
```

when I'm using this code and signing in with a phone number for the second it should actually prompt "this number already exists" but it isn't working and upon signing in with the same number again all the older names and passwords are being replaced by new ones....how can I solve this issue???

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your intent flow ;-

```
Intent intent= new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: actually what is happening ?

Comment: on using the same number again to sign up it's creating a new account in firebase database again overwriting the previous name and password